# Problem with RSS feed URL and special characters in tags

Tags: support, feed, hyperlinks

The following link doesn't work (Firefox) :

- https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=php5.3&sort=newest

Whereas this one works :

- https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=php5&sort=newest

The `.` (dot) seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the real problem here is simply that it isn't a tag on the site.

The period makes no difference; asp.net is fine:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=asp.net&sort=newest

We could perhaps return an empty feed, but...

Did you mean to add a hyphen? (php-5.3)

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=php-5.3&sort=newest

Comment: Ohhhhh I was sure that `php5.3` was a tag, it's actually `php-5.3` thanks! It's confusing though (`php5` is a tag). Thank you